# Running a Windows command line with arguments from Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, command-line-arguments

At the end of my notebook, I want to export an HTML version of it.
So I use the `jupyter nbconvert` command line utility in a notebook cell:

```
!jupyter nbconvert '$nb_path' --output '$nfname'
```

where `nb_path` contains the path to the notebook file (`.ipynb`) and `nfname` is a name that ends in `.html`.

This works fine on a Mac, but fails in Windows 10. There I get as output:

```
"This application is used to convert..."
```

that is, the same output as if I run just `jupyter nbconvert` (without arguments) in a cmd prompt.

If I open a cmd prompt and manually type the above command (with the actual file names instead of the variable names), then everything executes just fine.

So it seems that the `!` shortcut in jupyter notebook cell doesn't pass the arguments properly to the windows terminal. Is there a mechanism to do that, or do I have to resort to `Popen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
!jupyter nbconvert "$nb_path" --output "$nfname"
```

works for me on Windows 10

Comment: AAARRRGGHHHHH! I knew it was something simple. I did try enclosing the single quotes in double quotes and other variations, but did not try just double quotes. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept the answer if you think it is correct. Thanks!